# R-scatterplot3d rendering in Beaker Notebook

Tags: r, scatter3d, beaker-notebook

I'm trying to get the scatterplot3d package of R to render within a Beaker Notebook, but cannot get it to work. I can run the code without error, but the graphic is not displayed. Setting the scatterplot3d output to a variable and printing the variables gets:

input:

```
data(iris)  
test <- scatterplot3d(iris[,1:3])
test
```

output:

```
$xyz.convert
function (x, y = NULL, z = NULL) 
{
xyz <- xyz.coords(x, y, z)
if (angle > 2) {
    temp <- xyz$x
    xyz$x <- xyz$y
    xyz$y <- temp
}
y <- (xyz$y - y.add)/y.scal
return(list(x = xyz$x/x.scal + yx.f * y, y = xyz$z/z.scal + 
    yz.f * y))
}
<environment: 0x00000000048f8830>

$points3d
function (x, y = NULL, z = NULL, type = "p", ...) 
{
xyz <- xyz.coords(x, y, z)
if (angle > 2) {
    temp <- xyz$x
    xyz$x <- xyz$y
    xyz$y <- temp
}
y2 <- (xyz$y - y.add)/y.scal
x <- xyz$x/x.scal + yx.f * y2
y <- xyz$z/z.scal + yz.f * y2
mem.par <- par(mar = mar, usr = usr)
on.exit(par(mem.par))
if (type == "h") {
    y2 <- z.min + yz.f * y2
    segments(x, y, x, y2, ...)
    points(x, y, type = "p", ...)
}
else points(x, y, type = type, ...)
}
<environment: 0x00000000048f8830>

$plane3d
function (Intercept, x.coef = NULL, y.coef = NULL, lty = "dashed", 
lty.box = NULL, ...) 
{
if (!is.atomic(Intercept) && !is.null(coef(Intercept))) 
    Intercept <- coef(Intercept)
if (is.null(lty.box)) 
    lty.box <- lty
if (is.null(x.coef) && length(Intercept) == 3) {
    x.coef <- Intercept[if (angle > 2) 
        3
    else 2]
    y.coef <- Intercept[if (angle > 2) 
        2
    else 3]
    Intercept <- Intercept[1]
}
mem.par <- par(mar = mar, usr = usr)
on.exit(par(mem.par))
x <- x.min:x.max
ltya <- c(lty.box, rep(lty, length(x) - 2), lty.box)
x.coef <- x.coef * x.scal
z1 <- (Intercept + x * x.coef + y.add * y.coef)/z.scal
z2 <- (Intercept + x * x.coef + (y.max * y.scal + y.add) * 
    y.coef)/z.scal
segments(x, z1, x + y.max * yx.f, z2 + yz.f * y.max, lty = ltya, 
    ...)
y <- 0:y.max
ltya <- c(lty.box, rep(lty, length(y) - 2), lty.box)
y.coef <- (y * y.scal + y.add) * y.coef
z1 <- (Intercept + x.min * x.coef + y.coef)/z.scal
z2 <- (Intercept + x.max * x.coef + y.coef)/z.scal
segments(x.min + y * yx.f, z1 + y * yz.f, x.max + y * yx.f, 
    z2 + y * yz.f, lty = ltya, ...)
}
<environment: 0x00000000048f8830>

$box3d
function (...) 
{
mem.par <- par(mar = mar, usr = usr)
on.exit(par(mem.par))
lines(c(x.min, x.max), c(z.max, z.max), ...)
lines(c(0, y.max * yx.f) + x.max, c(0, y.max * yz.f) + z.max, 
    ...)
lines(c(0, y.max * yx.f) + x.min, c(0, y.max * yz.f) + z.max, 
    ...)
lines(c(x.max, x.max), c(z.min, z.max), ...)
lines(c(x.min, x.min), c(z.min, z.max), ...)
lines(c(x.min, x.max), c(z.min, z.min), ...)
}
<environment: 0x00000000048f8830>
```

I'm not sure if this functionality is possible with Beaker Notebooks, but thought I check here if anyone has any tips.

Thanks,
-pH+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. As part of my code, I was changing the working directory of R to more easily pull in datafiles from my project folder via:

```
setwd("C:/Users/macle/Desktop/UPC Masters/Semester 1/CN/MAI-CN/Final Project")
```

It appears that somewhere along the way, this breaks the ability of scatterplot3d to display the output in a Beaker Notebook.

I've instead just used absolute paths to load the files I need, which has solved the issue for me.

@spot Thanks for pointing me in the right direction and confirming the issue was on my end and not a limitation of Beaker.

Ps. I love working with Beaker, thanks for developing such a fantastic tool.

Comment: thank you, happy to hear it.  the lack of control over cwd is a problem, somewhere in the issue tracker, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me, just by making sure the library was loaded: https://pub.beakernotebook.com/#/publications/312f12ee-1619-11e6-8e18-afd4bf712b6e